# How can I use ASM lib in java to instrument an if-else block?

Tags: java, assembly, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

I've been trying to instrument branch-related code using ASM lib in java. Suppose this is a period of code I want to instrument:

```
        if (true) {
            System.out.println("true");
        } else {
            System.out.println("false");
        }
```

Here is my code for instrumentation:

```
            //put true on stack
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_1);
  
            //create labels
            Label elseLabel = new Label();
            Label endLabel = new Label();
            mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.IFEQ, elseLabel);

            // instrument code for the "if" block
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitLdcInsn("true");
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);

            mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, endLabel);
            mv.visitLabel(elseLabel);

            //instrument code for else block
            mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            mv.visitLdcInsn("false");
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);

            mv.visitLabel(endLabel);
```

The instrumented byte code can be shown and interpreted correctly with Intellij's own decompiler.

However, the code cannot be run, there is VerifyError
[image]

And this is the readable bytecode generated by running "javap -c" command.

```
 public void doSomething1();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokevirtual #5                  // Method doSomething:()V
       4: iconst_1
       5: invokestatic  #6                  // Method org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.assertTrue:(Z)V
       8: iconst_1
       9: ifeq          23
      12: getstatic     #44                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      15: ldc           #46                 // String true
      17: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      20: goto          31
      23: getstatic     #44                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      26: ldc           #48                 // String false
      28: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      31: return
}
```

Could you please help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: What is your expectation about what instrumentation means?  This looks like it should generate equivalent bytecode, but that's not the same thing as instrumenting existing bytecode.

Comment: I'm instrumenting this if-else block at the end of each called method. That is, I override visitInsn method. I check if the Opcode indicates it's a "return" statement, I  then insert byte codes before return statements.

Comment: How do you create your `ClassWriter`? Do you pass `ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAME` into it?

Comment: Em. I do use ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS. I followed your opinion and change it to COMPUTE_FRAME. It works!!! Thank you!
It seems that I used to use ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS and just copied the code. Now I need to really understand their differences.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in adding bytecode.
However, it is solved simply by passing ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAME rather than ClassWriter.ComputeMaxs.(Thanks Johannes Kuhn and anyone who helped me). And red-flagged VerifyError indicates that (though I  don't know).

COMPUTE_MAX seems to work for java5 or earlier.

Comment: You can still use `COMPUTE_MAX` if you generate the required stackmap frames by hand. But when inserting code with branches into existing code that may also have branches already, this can be quite challenging.